# Return Value in Promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I know this questions is asked several times in several ways. But I realy dont get it:

I have a promise with a resolved value. I can console.log this object and everything seems to be fine. I can see, what I want to see.

I use PouchDB and NuxtJS (VueJS)

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'

let testdb = new PouchDB('testdb');

let testDoc = function () {
  testdb.get('2').then(function (doc) {
    console.log(doc);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

This works great. My result is what I expect and hope to see:

```
{
   text: "testen", 
   _id: "2", 
   _rev: "1-c7e7c73d264aa5e6ed6b5cc10df35c5a"
}
```

Perfect. But now I am struggeling with returning this value, so other functions can access to it. Especially returning this data. In VueJS eg like that:

```
// ..
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         doc: testDoc
      }
   }
}
```

So I can access to it via instance. But ofcourse, If I do it like that, data is promise

```
data: [
   doc: promise
]
```

But I need the value, not what it is. I dont understand how to return the value.

I have read several How To´s. I guess, I understand the different between Callback and Promise. With both and async functions I get the same result. But all example are always with console.log(). But this works for me.

Has anyone an example hot to access this (scoped or nested?) value?

If I return the data:

```
let testdb = new PouchDB('testdb');

let testDoc = function () {
  testdb.get('2').then(function (doc) {
    return doc;
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Why hasnt `testDoc` the value now? Or where the hack is the value?

I always have done it via commiting the value into the vuex store. This also works great.

```
let fetchOrga = async function({ store }) {
  try {
    let orgaDoc = await orgadb.get('orga');
    store.commit('orgaUpdate', orgaDoc)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

But like I said, I want to have this data directly under control via IndexedDB

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533929/how-to-return-data-from-promise. You need to have two returns, one inside the promise function, and one for your testdb function. You can't get the value because you are not returning anything from your testdb function. Or better yet use async/await instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) to wait until promise resolve:

```
// nuxt.js way
async asyncData() {
  let testdb = new PouchDB('testdb');
  return {
    doc: await testdb.get('2'),
  };
},
```

---

UPD (by comments):

```
data() {
  return {
    isReady: false,
    doc: null,
  };
},
async mounted() {
  let testdb = new PouchDB('testdb');
  this.doc = await testdb.get('2');
  this.isReady = true;
},
```

Comment: nice way to use ```async/wait``` but i don't recommend this method it'will affect the mount of the component also you don't have much control on your errors also imagine if you want to add a loader of something before that ...

Comment: oh... you are right! Nuxt-pages have asyncData, but components - not. I'll update an answer.

Comment: wow. woooooow. Thank you very much. This matches what I need. Ist now an Object I can access to. 

And yes, It is on nuxt-page, not in component.

Answer (score 1):

In the mount of the component you should update your `state doc` then your doc will be available to work with anywhere in your inside your component.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      doc: [],
      error : ""
    }
  },
  mounted: () => {
    testdb.get('2').then(doc => {
      this.doc = doc;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      this.error = err;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`testDoc` in your example now contains a **function**. Not a promise nor the `doc` you're getting from the promnise. To get the actual `doc` you need to get inside the *promise*. Like this

```
let testdb = new PouchDB('testdb');

testdb.get('2').then(function (doc) {

    // Your doc is here
    console.log(doc);
    return doc;
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Alternatively you can use the [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) syntax, like this

```
let doc = await testdb.get('2');
// Your doc is here
console.log(doc);
```

Comment: ok, allright. But how can I access this `doc`from outside of that function?

Comment: You either return the promise, or return it as a normal variable in the `await` example. Either way, to get it in another function, you need to do the same process. You call it either with `.then()` or with `async/await`